# Using AD service account within SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, active-directory, etl

I have created connection manager within SSIS packages which has windows authentication and by default it is going to use my credentials to connect to a specific db.

[image]

I created project parameters that have connectionstring to dev, qa, prod.

[image]

and edited connection manager properties to give in expressions to use project parameters and automatically update package to use service account Userid and password.

[image]

But, my package has been defaulting to SQL server authentication and is failing when I am trying to connect to database.

Any help is much appreciated and would love to provide any necessary information.

Comment: how you are trying to execute the package? sql agent? stored procedure? dtexec? visual studio?

Comment: Are you using `Integrated Security=SSPI;` in your connection string?

Comment: @hadi - I am executing the package locally on my laptop

Comment: @digital.aaron - I have just included that in the connection string and it's working for the execute sql task but in DFT it is failing to connect to db. It's throwing up an error "Login failed"

Comment: You may have set up a db connection in your DFT that is trying to use a different type of authentication.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows Authentication, make sure your connection string(s) use `Integrated Security=SSPI;`. Also make sure all your database connections you use in your various tasks are all also set to use Windows Authentication. You may need to use an expression to set their connection strings per environment as well.

Comment: Can you explain why we need to use Integrated Security=SSPI in connection string. Thank you!!

Comment: That's how you tell SQL Server to interpret your username and password using Windows Authentication. If you don't specify, SQL will default to SQL Authentication.